# ken ui datepicker

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui

I have a kendo ui datepicker and I want my selected date should be displayed in a label.  I want to bind the selected date to a label.What code i have to add in a my .cs page?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#date").kendoDatePicker();
           });
 </script>     
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div  style="width: 155px;">
            <input id="date" />
        </div>
       <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the `<input id="date" />` to asp.net control eg:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

and then get the rendered id of the text box as:

```
$("#<%=txtDate.ClientID%>").kendoDatePicker();
```

The `asp:label` is not help here, meaning is not post back the value that you get of the date. On code behind you read the value of the text box using the `txtDate.Text`

How ever if you actually wont to place the value on the label you can use [the `change` of the kendo](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/datepicker#change) date picker as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#date").kendoDatePicker({
            change: function(e) {
                $("#<%=lblDate.ClientID%>").text($("#date").val());
            }
        });                
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: But i want the date should be displayed in a label and not in a textbox.

Comment: @user1778868 I have update my question with direct answer to the question.